# DPDK 20.11 - IPv4 Fragmentation - indirect pool gets exhausted

Tags: c, dpdk

I m trying to fragmentation an IPv4 packet using the below logic:

```
~after pkts ingress~

struct rte_port_ring_writer *p = port_out->h_port;

pool_direct = rte_mempool_lookup("MEMPOOL0");  
pool_indirect = rte_mempool_lookup("MEMPOOL1");

printf("before frag mempool size d %d in %d\n",rte_mempool_avail_count(pool_direct),rte_mempool_avail_count(pool_indirect));

struct rte_mbuf *frag_pkts[MAX_FRAG_SIZE];  
int out_pkts =    rte_ipv4_fragment_packet (m, frag_pkts, n_frags, ip_mtu,pool_direct, pool_indirect);

printf("after frag mempool size d %d in %d\n",rte_mempool_avail_count(pool_direct),rte_mempool_avail_count(pool_indirect));

if(out_pkts > 0)  
port_out->ops.f_tx_bulk(port_out->h_port,frag_pkts,RTE_LEN2MASK(out_pkts, uint64_t));  
else  
printf("frag failed\n");

rte_pktmbuf_free>(m);                       //free parent pkt
```

Now the problem here is the indirect mempool gets exhausted. As a result after few burst of packets the fragmentation fails due to -ENOMEM. I quite cannot understand why the PMD doesn't free and put back the mempool obj back to MEMPOOL1. Is it highly unlikely it is because of NIC ports being bounded to MEMPOOL0 and frag pkts from MEMPOOL1 being egressed.

Please find the log below for the above snippet which prints the available slots in direct (d) and indirect (in) mempools:

before frag mempool size d 2060457 in 2095988
after frag mempool size d 2060344 in 2095952
before frag mempool size d 2060361 in 2095945
after frag mempool size d 2060215 in 2095913
.
.
.
before frag mempool size d 2045013 in 0
after frag mempool size d 2045013 in 0
before frag mempool size d 2045013 in 0
after frag mempool size d 2045013 in 0
before frag mempool size d 2045013 in 0

I can see the direct mempool reduce and increase as packets ingress and drop/egress as expected. I can also confirm I receive the initial burst of fragmented packets equal to MEMPOOL1 size. Any inputs towards understanding the cause of the problem is much appreciated.

P.S: We had the same problem in dpdk17.11. We had to refractor the rte_ipv4_fragment_packet() to not use indirect chaining of frags instead just generate them.

Edit:
DPDK version - 20.11
Env - linux - centos 7
PMD - i40e - **using bond in mode4**
Pkt size - 128
MTU - 70

Mempools are created with rte_pktmbuf_pool_create(),
thus with no SC/SP flag (defaults to MC/MP). Also always n_frags < MAX_FRAG_SIZE.

Thanks & Regards,
Vishal Mohan

Comment: please update the question with the following information `1) DPDK version 2) Linux or BSD or Windows 3) NIC PMD in use 4) Proc-info memopool result 5) please update the packet size of original packet m 5) is n_frags == MAX_FRAG_SIZE 6) ip_mtu value 7) what are parameter values used for creating direct and indirect mempool`. @VishalMohan looking forward to the update

Comment: Also, there is an example in DPDK `ip_fragmentation` which exercises the same API. Can you please confirm you are able to reproduce the same error. @VishalMohan looking forward to the update

Comment: Hi @VipinVarghese, thank you for the response. I've updated the required information in the OP. Also will test the ip_frag example given by DPDK. Does using bond make any difference at all ? AFAIK bond pmd is only responsible for selecting a bond port and still the NIC PMD is responsible for egress and mbuf memory management. Please do correct me if this understanding is wrong

Comment: there is gap in understanding, I believe you have my skype id please reach on skype for further discussion

Comment: Hi @VishalMohan waiting for sync up from your end.

Comment: HI @VishalMohan are there any updates for sync up from your end?

Comment: Hi @VipinVarghese reached out through mail for further discussions. Thank you for your time.

Comment: hi @Vishal thanks for the email, I have been waiting patiently for you and your team call on skype for sync. I have not received any. As per the email conversation, there is no error in DPDK API but it is in the custom application. I will wait for a day, then update the answer. Accept or upvote to close the ticket.

Comment: Hi @VipinVarghese, yes i can confirm the fragment api is working as expected from the given example. But not when in our application. But the same fragment api when refactored to not use indirect buffer chaining, everything is working as expected. Not really sure what to deduce from it. Apologies for the delay.

Comment: based on the email conversation and comments answer for your current issue is discussed and updated. Please accept and upvote to close the current question. Please open the new question with relevant details focusing on application logic.

Comment: @Vipin Varghese: Q: What exactly would this "new question" be?  What details should the OP provide?

Comment: @paulsm4 after the email discussion on this question, it has been found out the real cause of problem is how the API is misused. The new question asked by @VishalMohan why the current code snippet (shared in the question) has no seg-fault with BOND PMD and has SEG Fault with I40E PMD. I have requested @VishalMohan `to open a new question which focuses on the same` and close the current one as there is no issue with DPDK API in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPDK API ***rte_ipv4_fragment_packet*** is used under both `testpmd` and DPDK example `ip_fragementation`. These are also included under the DPDK test suite which is run for each release too.

**Based on the internal test and proper use of API for example `Ip_fragementation` the issue is not been able to reproduce. Hence the API leaking memory pool buffers are highly unlikely other than some special corner case (which is yet to be found).**

Based on the code snippet analysis following could be the cause of mempool exhaust

1. fail to free direct buffer after fragmentation
2. fail to free one or more fragments from the indirect buffer when tx_burst fails.

[EDIT-1] based on the email update and comments, there is indeed no problem with DPDK API ***rte_ipv4_fragment_packet***. The issue is from Application logic, with new behaviour as

1. DPDK BOND PMD leads to mempool exhaustion with current code snippet
2. DPDK BOND PMD has no issues with DPDK example with ***rte_ipv4_fragment_packet***
3. DPDK i40e PMD has an issue with the current code snippet
4. DPDK i40e PMD has no issue with dpdk example ***rte_ipv4_fragment_packet***

Hence the issue is with sample code snippet and usage and not DPDK API.

Comment: Thanks for the support Vipin. Yes everything is good with the examples. But not when used along with our app. There is no memleak for sure because post frag we tx the packet to bond port (Assuming pmd will free the mbuf). Will revise the app logic and update if any.